# Custom authorization IActionResults in aspnet-5 mvc-6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-mvc, actionresult

In ASP.NET 4 MVC5, I had this class that allowed me to return custom responses for unauthenticated responses to JSON endpoints. Here it is.

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (IsAjax(filterContext))
        {
            filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
            {
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
                Data = new
                {
                    success = false,
                    error = "You must be signed in."
                }
            };
        }
        else
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }

    private bool IsAjax(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        return filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetFilterAttributes(true).OfType<AjaxAttribute>().FirstOrDefault() !=
                null;
    }
}
```

However, in MVC6, the new `AuthorizeAttribute` is no overrides for creating custom `IActionResult` results. How do I do this in MVC6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out after looking at the source.

```
public class CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents : CookieAuthenticationEvents
{
    Func<CookieRedirectContext, Task> _old;
    public CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents()
    {
        _old = OnRedirectToLogin;
        OnRedirectToLogin = OnCustomRedirectToLogin;
    }

    public Task OnCustomRedirectToLogin(CookieRedirectContext context)
    {
        var actionContext = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IActionContextAccessor>();
        if (actionContext.ActionContext == null)
            return _old(context);

        if (actionContext.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.FilterDescriptors.Any(x => x.Filter is AjaxAttribute))
        {
            // this is an ajax request, return custom JSON telling user that they must be authenticated.
            var serializerSettings = context
                .HttpContext
                .RequestServices
                .GetRequiredService<IOptions<MvcJsonOptions>>()
                .Value
                .SerializerSettings;

            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

            using (var writer = new HttpResponseStreamWriter(context.Response.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(writer))
                {
                    jsonWriter.CloseOutput = false;
                    var jsonSerializer = JsonSerializer.Create(serializerSettings);
                    jsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, new
                    {
                        success = false,
                        error = "You must be signed in."
                    });
                }
            }

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
        else
        {
            // this is a normal request to an endpoint that is secured.
            // do what ASP.NET used to do.
            return _old(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, use this event class as follows:

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.Events = new CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents();
});
```

ASP.NET 5 sure made simple things harder to do. Granted though, I can now customize things at a more granular level without effecting other pieces. Also, the source code is amazingly easy to read/understand. I am pretty happy having the confidence that any issue I am having can easily be identified as a bug or resolved by looking at the source.

Cheers to the future!

Comment: Out of interest, what's wrong with letting a 401 or 403 make it back to your client side and reacting accordingly? That's the sort of scenario we're aiming for (and not using cookie auth for ajax, because of CSRF problems). That's why it's hard to do what you want, it's not what we were expecting folks to do.

Comment: Because in my javascript, jquery error callbacks are terminal errors that halt workflow, and 200 requests with with error=true are expected errors that are a part of the workflow. Being unauthenticated is a error I expect. It make my client side code simpler. This isn't a published/public API, so I'm ok with not sticking to conventions.

Comment: Also, when it comes to enclosed applications with unpublished APIs, you shouldn't use conventions for conventions sake. Guess what SO is doing? ;) http://i.imgur.com/qqTFGWP.png

Answer (score 1):

A good point has been made by @blowdart in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34375083/custom-authorization-iactionresults-in-aspnet-5-mvc-6/34396844#comment56534638_34393964) about whether returning 401/403 should be the expected behaviour. In any case, I have tried a different approach for doing what the OP was asking, modifying the behavior of the default MVC authorization filters so that we return a json when user is unauthorized.

First thing I did was creating a new `IAsyncAuthorizationFilter` that will format the unauthorized result as a json for ajax request. It will basically:

1. Wrap an existing filter
2. Execute the wrapped filter
3. In case the user is unauthorized by the wrapped filter, return a json for ajax requests

This would be the `CustomJsonAuthorizationFilter` class:

```
public class CustomJsonAuthorizationFilter : IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
    private AuthorizeFilter wrappedFilter;
    public CustomJsonAuthorizationFilter(AuthorizeFilter wrappedFilter)
    {
        this.wrappedFilter = wrappedFilter;
    }

    public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Filters.AuthorizationContext context)
    {
        await this.wrappedFilter.OnAuthorizationAsync(context);
        if(context.Result != null && IsAjaxRequest(context))
        {
            context.Result = new JsonResult(new
            {
                success = false,
                error = "You must be signed in."
            });
        }
        return;
    }

    //This could be an extension method of the HttpContext/HttpRequest
    private bool IsAjaxRequest(Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Filters.AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        return filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest";
    }
}
```

Then I have created an `IApplicationModelProvider` in order to wrap all existing [`AuthorizeFilter`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/Filters/AuthorizeFilter.cs) with the new custom filter. The `AuthroizeFilter` is added by [`AuthorizationApplicationModelProvider`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/ApplicationModels/AuthorizationApplicationModelProvider.cs), but the new provider will be run after the default one since the order of the default provider is -990.

```
public class CustomFilterApplicationModelProvider : IApplicationModelProvider
{
    public int Order
    {
        get { return 0; }
    }

    public void OnProvidersExecuted(ApplicationModelProviderContext context)
    {
        //Do nothing
    }

    public void OnProvidersExecuting(ApplicationModelProviderContext context)
    {
        this.ReplaceFilters(context.Result.Filters);
        foreach(var controller in context.Result.Controllers)
        {
            this.ReplaceFilters(controller.Filters);
            foreach (var action in controller.Actions)
            {
                this.ReplaceFilters(action.Filters);
            }
        }
    }

    private void ReplaceFilters(IList<IFilterMetadata> filters)
    {
        var authorizationFilters = filters.OfType<AuthorizeFilter>().ToList();
        foreach (var filter in authorizationFilters)
        {
            filters.Remove(filter);
            filters.Add(new CustomJsonAuthorizationFilter(filter));
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, update `ConfigureServices` in startup with the new application model provider:

```
services.TryAddEnumerable(
            ServiceDescriptor.Transient<IApplicationModelProvider, CustomFilterApplicationModelProvider>());
```

Comment: More than one way to skin a cat! I like this approach because it stays in MVC world. My solution was in middleware with a *peek* (```IActionContextAccessor```) into the MVC world.

Comment: Also, with regards to @blowdart, when it comes to enclosed applications with unpublished APIs, you shouldn't use conventions for conventions sake. Guess what SO is doing? ;) http://i.imgur.com/qqTFGWP.png